# Definitions of Fences in C++ Standard [atomics.fences in n4713]

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, memory-barriers

[atomics.fences.2]:

> A release fence A synchronizes with an acquire fence B if there exist atomic operations X and Y, both operating on some atomic object M, such that A is sequenced before X, X modifies M, Y is sequenced before B, and Y reads the value written by X or a value written by any side effect in the hypothetical release sequence X would head if it were a release operation.

So a potential sample code is like:

```
std::atomic<uint32_t> M;

//Thread K
std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order::release);  // release fence A sequenced before
M.store(1, std::memory_order::relaxed); // operation X: operating on atomic object M

//Thread J
M.load(std::memory_order::relaxed); // operation Y: operating on atomic object M -- reading sequenced before
std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order::acquire); // acquire fence B
```

Questions:

1. Does the code above reflect what [atomics.fences.2] says?  If not, what should it look like?
2. I thought the release fence should be sequenced after operation X because the release fence is trying to make the previous store visible to other threads with respect to the acquire fence (B), and so acquire fence B should be sequenced before operation Y.  No?

Comment: I don't have enough experience with the C++ threading model to give a definitive answer, but subquestion 1 could probably use a bit of clarification--The term "correct" is possibly ambiguous, and specifying exactly what guarantees you need from the code as a whole might be more helpful.

Comment: @ζ-- thanks for pointing out.  fixed.  let me know if it sounds better.  English isn't my native...:(

Comment: "Does the code above reflect what [atomics.fences.2] says?" - Yes, in your code `release fence A` is *synchronizes with* `acquire fence B`. So whatever operation you will got in the thread K before the `release fence A`, its effect will be seen with guarantee by any operation in the thread J after `acquire fence B`. Not sure what do you want to ask in the second question. But note on "Y reads the **value written by X**" in the definition.

Comment: `Y reads the value written by X ` seems that it has nothing to do with the fences because both operations X and Y are operating on an atomic variable M...so even without the pair of fences, Y could read what X has written anyway.  No?

Comment: "Y could read what X has written anyway." - Y **could** read the value written **before** the X. E.g. if Y comes some time before the X is issued. Or if Y comes some time after the X, but due to the caching the effect of the X has not been propagated to the other CPU yet. In both that cases the cited paragraph is **not applied**. It is applied only when Y reads a value written by X. E.g. if before the X value of M was 0, X writes 1 and value read by Y is 1 too, then you may be sure that Y read the value written by X.

Comment: Again, the cited paragraph has no intention to deduce, what  is a value read by the Y - it is **prerequisite** of the paragraph itself, that Y read the value written by X. The intention of the paragraph to guarantee the value of some **other variable**, even non-atomic one. It that other variable is written before the release fence in the thread `K`, and thread `J` will read that variable after the acquire fence, then this reading would return the value written in the `thread K`. This is an example of the application of given paragraph.

Comment: Thanks for elaborating.  What the paragraph confused me is -- atomic operations X and Y on atomic object M all seem unnecessary to be mentioned because like you said, `The intention of the paragraph to guarantee the value of some other variable, even non-atomic one`

Comment: "atomic operations X and Y on atomic object M all seem unnecessary" - No, these operations are very important here. And that Y reads the value written by X is very important too. Otherwise, deduction on other variable's value won't work.

Comment: @Tsyvarev "_due to the caching the effect of the X has not been propagated to the other CPU yet_" Can you explain that "caching effect"?

Comment: Caching in CPU is a large topic, it cannot be explained in the comments. BTW, handling CPU caching effects is one of the main purpose of atomic variables and fences.

Comment: Which language version do you use? Where is your quote from?

Comment: @curiousguy the quote comes from the standard draft [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4713.pdf).  I believe the draft is for C++17.

Comment: @HCSF So, latest evolution of the std, not an out of date version? Why do you include multiple language tags?

Comment: I vaguely remember that C++11 had the same section (at least C++20 [does](https://eel.is/c++draft/atomics.fences)); hence, I tagged C++11 and C++17.  Probably should have tagged C++14 and C++20 as well.